# How to match n character long strings separated by '+'-signs?

Tags: regex

I am using this Regex `(\(?(F[0-9]{3}\+?\-?)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}\+?\-?)*\)?v?)+`.

Examples of strings I want to match:

- F123
- F123+098
- F123+YYY
- F123+F456+890+456
- F123+F456+890+-456
- (F123+F456+890+456)v(F123)
- (F123+F456+890+456)v(F123+098)

Examples of strings I don't want to match:

- F1234+
- F123+
- F123+098+
- F123+456789
- (F123+F456+890+456)vF123)
- (F123+F456+890+456)v(F123+09898)
- (F123+F456+890+456)v(F123+098

I think I need some kind of negative look-ahead to make sure that there is a `+` in between if I match a second group or a `)v(` if I match a new instance but I can't seem to figure out how.

I also would like to make sure that it only matches when the entire input matches the Regex.

Maybe of help: https://regexr.com/4irbv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one option is to use repeating groups and an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match the part without the opening and closing parenthesis and to match the part with the parenthesis where the v is in between.

```
^(?:F[0-9]{3}(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*$|\(F[0-9]{3}(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*\)v\(F[0-9]{3}(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*\))$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `F[0-9]{3}` Match F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*` Repeat 0+ times a `+`, optional `-`, F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*` Repeat 0+ times a `+`, optional `-` and and 3 times any of the listed
- `|` Or

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `F[0-9]{3}` Match F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*` Repeat 0+ times `+`, optional `-`, F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*` Match 0+ times `+`, optional `-` and 3 times any of the listed
  - `\)v\(` Match `)v(`
  - `F[0-9]{3}` Match F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?F[0-9]{3})*` Match 0+ times `+`, optional `-`, F and 3 digits
  - `(?:\+-?[0-9a-zA-Z]{3})*` Match 0+ times `+`, optional `-` and 3 times any of the listed
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tX6mSa/1)

Comment: You are my hero

Comment: To account for the letters and +- I ended up with: `(?:^F[0-9]{3}(?:\+\-?F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})*$|\(F[0-9]{3}(?:\+\-?F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})*\)v\(F[0-9]{3}(?:\+F[0-9]{3})*(?:\+\-?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3})*\))$`

Comment: You could adjust it to your requirements.  Should there be only either `-` or `+` or can there be both? In that case you could use a character class `[-+]?` to optionally match one of both.

Comment: There is always a `+` and sometimes a `+-`